# Deleting a record from dataset and sql server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to delete a record from a DataTable and then update the database that it is attached to.

I delete a row of my DataGridView and then update my Dataset using:

```
                Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.Rows.RemoveAt(Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index)
                ds1.AcceptChanges()
                Tab2_DGVDuty.Refresh()
```

I then call my adapter.update as below:

```
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            Dim DutyDetails As String = "SELECT * from MyTable"

            adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(DutyDetails, SQLConn)
            adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
            adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand

            Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

            adapter.Update(ds1.Tables("DT_Table"))
```

But when i reload the data my record is still there. If I change a value and update this works fine but for some reason the delete doesnt.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
OK I changed my delete to the following as suggested below:

```
ds1.Tables("DT_Table").Rows(Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
```

This is attached to a button, it deletes fine the first time but on the second press to delete another record nothing happens. If I use

```
ds1.AcceptChanges()
```

then it works fine. However, if i use the above then my code below does not delete anything from the database:

```
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
            Dim DutyDetails As String = "SELECT * from MyTable"

            adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(DutyDetails, SQLConn)
            adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
            adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand

            Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

            adapter.Update(ds1.Tables("DT_Table"))
```

Comment: You need to create your data adapter and associate it with a data table, or something, like da.Fill(dt) before they make changes for the da.update to do anything.  You can't create a ds, delete a row, create a data adapter, associate it with the ds, then update the da and expect it to know about changes to the ds.  Is that what you were doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't want to remove the `DataRow` from the `DataTable`, you want to [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx) it

   ```
   ds1.Tables("DT_Table").Rows(Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()
   ```
2. Don't call `ds1.AcceptChanges()` afterwards since the `Update` will not recognize that this row has changed anymore then because it will change it's `RowState` to `Unchanged`.  `DataAdapter.Update` calls `AcceptChanges` as the last step implicitely,  not you.
3. I assume that `Tab2_DGVDuty` is a `DataGridView` and not the `DataTable`, i've taken that into account above.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the .Delete did not work for me as it gave me a 'delete is not a member..', but removing the Ds1.AcceptChanges now updates SQL correctly. Thanks very much.

Comment: @user1295053: A row that is removed from a datatable will not cause a delete statement to be executed if this is what you wanted. So you should really use [`DataRow.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx). I assume you have not used my code but something like `Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.Rows.Delete(..)` which does not work, of course. If you want to delete a `DataRow` in the database, you have to change it's `RowState` to `Deleted` and then use a `DataAdapter` to update the row, table or DataSet.

Comment: I used your exact code of `Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.Rows(Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index).Delete() and received an error message as I said. The line I used in my code above works fine, so not sure what you mean as it is deleting from the datatable and the database.

Comment: @user1295053: So i think that `Me.Tab2_DGVDuty` is a `DataGridView` and not the `DataTable` you have mentioned.

Comment: @TimSchmelter +1 I also think so. @user Try `Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.Rows(Me.Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index).Row.Delete()`

Comment: It is indeed a DataGridView and .Row.Delete returns an error also. I am now having a problem due to me removing ds1.acceptchanges where I can't delete more than once. as I get an error "Deleted row information can not be accessed through the row".

Comment: and sorry, I'm not sure how to highlight code in these comments sections

Comment: @user1295053: You should not post code in comments, instead you might want to edit your question to add details or what you have tried. It's not helpful if you always abbreviate the code. So we don't know what you have deleted now. You can try `ds1.Tables("DT_Table").Rows(Tab2_DGVDuty.CurrentRow.Index).Delete()`

Comment: @user1295053: You should not call `AcceptChanges` yourself. You should `Delete` the `DataRow` (which actually just changes the [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate.aspx) to [`Deleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) but does not delete the row from database. Therefore you need to use the `DataAdapter`. It's `Update` method will loop every row to find rows which `RowState` is <> `Unchanged` and call the appropriate command(like your delete-command). Then you have to Databind your `DataGridView`.

Comment: But what if the user wants to delete several rows in the datagridview before these changes are saved?