# Error while deleting record from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, delete-record

I need some help with delete record from database.

I am trying to delete a record from a table in my SQL Server database.

Am I missing something?

```vb
  Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
     _DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(CInt(txtCurrent.Text) - 1).Delete()
     ' tho, it can remove the deleted rows
     ' we cannot call the DataSet.AcceptChanges method
     ' because the DataAdapter would not recognize the delete row
     ' by the time DataAdapter.Update(DataSet) is called.
     EnableNavigation()
     cmdSave.Enabled = True  ' let user update the underlying database
     ' after deleting the current record, the current record still points to the
     ' deleted record (though it cannot be updated). 
     ' The user must MoveNext/Back to view other records.
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DataRow.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not delete this row from database. It  marks the `DataRow`'s [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as [deleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This will be checked from a `DataAdapter` if you call [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If it's state is `Deleted` it will look for its according [`DeleteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you have to provide.

So you need to provide a [`DeleteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your `DataAdapter` which is the sql  to delete the row from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You want to Delete it

```
_DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(CInt(txtCurrent.Text) - 1).Delete()

 Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
 Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
 Dim DutyDetails As String = "SELECT * from MyTable"

 adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(DutyDetails, SQLConn)
 adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
 adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand

 Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

  adapter.Update(_DataSet.Tables("0"))
```

Source:  [Deleting a record from dataset and sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833006/deleting-a-record-from-dataset-and-sql-server)

Comment: I had this Error :                                                 Error while deleting record on table...Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: datatable

Answer (score 0):

You refer to the table as `_DataSet.Tables(0)`, then refer to it later as `_DataSet.Tables("0")` I bet one of the two is incorrect.